# WinXP in VirtualBox 3.1.4 corrupts files read from drive shared with W7-64 host

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a reproduceable problem reading **some** files from a shared drive, I get "corrupt data" (well, the file appears to be "damaged"). Copying the complete directory to a local drive of my VM, I can read these files w/o problems.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sharing your host PC's folder using VirtualBox's inbuilt options? You could instead try sharing a folder in W7 (right-click the folder and click **Sharing**) and access the network share from your XP virtual machine. Network shares can be set to read-only mode which would protect your files from being edited/damaged by the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks George - I had indeed used the Shared Folders of VirtualBox, but when I mapped that path it fixed the probs! That has slightly damaged my trust into VB :(